# Install OpenVPN server and Easy-RSA

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I am trying to install OpenVPN and Easy-RSA. However, this machine can not access anything outside its network. So I can't use apt-get to install it.

I downloaded OpenVPN tar file (on my local computer and used scp to transfer it over) and I believe I installed it correctly by running these commands:

```
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

When I do `openvpn --version`, I get this:

```
OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Oct 12 2015
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014, LZO 2.06
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=yes enable_fragment=yes enable_http_proxy=yes enable_iproute2=no enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_lzo_stub=no enable_management=yes enable_multi=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_password_save=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=no enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_small=no enable_socks=yes enable_ssl=yes enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=no with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_plugindir='$(libdir)/openvpn/plugins' with_sysroot=no
```

So I think that's fine. I downloaded and transferred easy-rsa from here: https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa, but I don't know how to install it.

What do I need to do? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to simply run `easyrsa/easyrsa`. It's a shell script and looks like it doesn't need building.

Comment: Am I downloading the right tar.gz/zip file? I don't have a `easyrsa/easyrsa`. Which release did you download?

Comment: I see that now. I was just looking at contents of the git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest zip file from the "releases" list on GitHub. Right now it's version 3.0.0. The `easyrsa` file is the script you want.

```
$ wget -q https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/releases/download/3.0.0/EasyRSA-3.0.0.tgz
$ tar -xzf EasyRSA-3.0.0.tgz
$ ls
EasyRSA-3.0.0/  EasyRSA-3.0.0.tgz
$ cd EasyRSA-3.0.0/
$ ls easyrsa
easyrsa*
```

You can also make a link to it if you need to:

```
$ ln -s $(pwd)/easyrsa /usr/bin/easyrsa
$ easyrsa

Easy-RSA 3 usage and overview

USAGE: easyrsa [options] COMMAND [command-options]

...
```

Comment: Is `/easyrsa` supposed to be `/easyrsa3`? I'm guessing it is since I have the executable easyrsa in that folder.

Comment: The file you want is that executable `easyrsa` and the commands I provided create a link to it in `/usr/bin/` (assuming you're already in the `EasyRSA-3.0.0/` directory.